# Pytorch GPU on windows 10 error: Windows not yet supported for torch.compile

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error

I have been trying to get either tensorflow or pytorch with GPU support running on windows 10. Recently, I went back to school after 23 years to get a PHD. This semester I am taking a course using deep learning. During my previous graduate degree, I did a great deal of neural net development but that was all in C between 1999-2001. So, I am also dealing with a learning curve on python and python environments. Before my course begins, I have been working to get my development environment running.

During this time, I have learned that tensorflow requires WSL2 to run. I spent about 20 hours trying and retrying to get this working. This lead me to try pytorch. I first tried using anaconda installs that ended in the same errors. I later used the pytorch anaconda install and the pip install. All of my attempts to get pytorch working have ended in the same error.

Windows is not yet supported for torch.compile

Here is the output of nvidia-smi

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 546.12                 Driver Version: 546.12       CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro M4000M                WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P0              26W / 100W |      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I do not see this stated anywhere in the documentation. I must be doing something wrong.

my install script after I created a new .venv

```
pip  install jupyter
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
pip install pandas
pip install scikit-learn
```

I ran this code:

```
import sys
import platform
import torch
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk

has_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
has_mps = getattr(torch,'has_mps',False)
device = "mps" if getattr(torch,'has_mps',False) \
    else "gpu" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

print(f"Python Platform: {platform.platform()}")
print(f"PyTorch Version: {torch.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
print(f"system platform: {sys.platform} {platform.architecture()}")
print(f"Pandas {pd.__version__}")
print(f"Scikit-Learn {sk.__version__}")
print("NVIDIA/CUDA GPU is", "available" if has_gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")    
print(f"Target device is {device}")
```

results of code:

```
Python Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
PyTorch Version: 2.1.2+cu121

Python 3.11.6 (tags/v3.11.6:8b6ee5b, Oct  2 2023, 14:57:12) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]
system platform: win32 ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
Pandas 2.1.4
Scikit-Learn 1.3.2
NVIDIA/CUDA GPU is available
Target device is gpu
```

I then try to run this example:

```
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin = torch.nn.Linear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.nn.functional.relu(self.lin(x))

mod = MyModule()
opt_mod = torch.compile(mod)
print(opt_mod(torch.randn(10, 100)))
```

This results in:> RuntimeError: Windows not yet supported for torch.compile

What am I doing wrong? Does pytorch not work on windows?
I have tried this on two other computers with the exact same results.
My environment has been varied by using python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.12.

I do not see anything on the pytorch website that states windows isn't supported.

Also, I dug into the error and found this:

```
def check_if_dynamo_supported():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        raise RuntimeError("Windows not yet supported for torch.compile")
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 12):
        raise RuntimeError("Python 3.12+ not yet supported for torch.compile")
```

This leads me to believe that either pytorch really does not support windows, or my configuration is wrong.

I have gone through several tutorials on youtube including Jeff Heaton's site and Francois Chollet's github page.

It seems that pytorch is the proper direction, but I need to get this working.

Comment: read this - see if it helps: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/8277